# Property does not exist on type Observable on Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

A type Observable object seems to be undefined on the template only when I'm using two-way binding to access its properties. When I tried accessing the property using {{interpolation}} syntax, it works. As an example: `<h1>{{flight.airline}}</h1>` works but `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="airline" name="airline" [(ngModel)]="flight.airline">` doesn't. Any element that uses two-way binding are having this issue.

I tried using the elvis operator `?.` and using `*ngIf` directive thinking that it's because the data was just initially unavailable but the same error shows up. If anyone can point me what I'm doing wrong, I'd truly appreciate it

flight-edit.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Flight Scheduler</h1>
    <div class="col-lg-8 ">
       <h3 *ngIf="success" class="text-success">Successfully updated!</h3> 
       <h4 class="float-right"><small>All fields are required</small></h4>
       <div class="row well center">
          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
             <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div *ngIf="flight" class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                      <label>Airline</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="airline" name="airline" [(ngModel)]="flight.airline">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                      <label>Flight Number</label>
                      <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="flight_no" [(ngModel)]="flight.flight_no">
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="border:1px solid #ced4da; padding:10px; border-radius: 5px;">
                   <label>Trip Type</label>
                   <div *ngIf="flight" class="radio">
                      <ng-container *ngFor="let trip_type of trip_types; let i=index">
                          <label for="radios-{{i}}" style="margin-right:20px">
                          <input type="radio" name="trip_type" id="radios-{{i}}" 
                          [checked]="flight.trip_type==trip_type"
                          [value]="trip_type"
                          (change)="flight.trip_type=trip_type">
                         {{trip_type}}
                         </label>   
                      </ng-container>                   
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="flight" class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                      <label>Departure Airport</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="departure_airport" [(ngModel)]="flight.departure_airport">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                      <label>Arrival Airport</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="arrival_airport" [(ngModel)]="flight.arrival_airport">
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="flight" class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                      <label>Departure Date</label>
                      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="departure_date" [(ngModel)]="flight.departure_date">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                      <label>Return Date</label>
                      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="return_date" [(ngModel)]="flight.return_date">
                   </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Submit</button>                                               
             </div>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

flight-edit.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, ObservedValueOf } from "rxjs";
import { Flight } from "../models/flight";
import { FlightService } from "../services/flight.service";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flight-edit',
  templateUrl: './flight-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flight-edit.component.css']
})
export class FlightEditComponent implements OnInit {

  flight: Observable<Flight>;
  flight_id: number;
  success: boolean = false;
  trip_types = ["One Way","Round Trip","Multiple Destinations"];

  constructor(private flightService: FlightService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.flight_id = Number(params.get("id"));
      }
    );
    this.loadFlightData();
  }

  loadFlightData(){
    this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.flight = data;
          }
        );
  }
  updateFlight(){
    this.flightService.updateFlight(this.flight_id,this.flight)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.flight = data as Observable<Flight>;
            this.success = true;
          },
          error => console.log("Oops.  Cannot update! " + error)
        );
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.updateFlight();
  }

}
```

flight.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { Flight } from '../models/flight'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FlightService {

  private endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/flights/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getFlight(id: number): Observable<any>{
      return this.http.get(this.endpoint + id)
    }

    //GET all flights
    getAllFlights(): Observable<any>{
      // console.log(this.http.get(this.endpoint))
      return this.http.get(this.endpoint)
    }

    //POST - add new flight
    flightCreate(flight: Flight): Observable<object>{
      return this.http.post(this.endpoint, flight)
    }

    //PUT - update
    updateFlight(id: number, payload: any): Observable<object> {
      return this.http.put(this.endpoint + id, payload)
    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be binding ngModel to an observable and from looking at your code it looks like you set flight inside a subscription so it should be just Flight! There's also a few other issues in your code e.g. you're not disposing of the the subscription inside the getflight method when the component is destroyed which will lead to a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we need to do some changes.

### In the `FlightEditComponent`

```js
// Comment the line below, let's change the attribute name and type
// flight: Observable<Flight>;
_flight$ = new BehaviorSubject<Flight | null>(null);

...

ngOnDestroy() {
  // best practice: complete all your subjects on component removal
  if(this._flight$ && !this._flight$.closed) {
    this._fligth$.complete();
  }
}

...

loadFlightData(){
  this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id)
    .subscribe(data => this._flight$.next(data));
}
```

### In the template

Replace this:

```html
<div *ngIf="flight" class="row">
```

with this:

```html
<div *ngIf="_flight$ | async as flight" class="row">
```

Comment: you could also change flight to flight$ in the component.ts and he wouldn't have to change flight everywhere

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. Sorry for the noob question but why doesn't observable work in this case? @julianobrasil

Comment: An observable is just a higher-order function that eventually emits a value. You were setting a function to all of your form fields. If you intend to work with angular, you get to know reactive programming. It's hard at the beginning, but once you change your mindset it's a game-changer. Just google for it. Once you start learning, a good reference is https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators.

Comment: I'll echo @julianobrasil here. The learning curve is steep but once you wrap your head around it and get comfortable with it it creates such nice code and is great for performance as well.